# Python Enclosing Words With Quotes In A String

Tags: python, string, csv

For Python I'm opening a csv file that appears like:

```
    jamie,london,uk,600087
    matt,paris,fr,80092
    john,newyork,ny,80071
```

How do I enclose the words with quotes in the csv file so it appears like:

```
    "jamie","london","uk","600087"
    etc...
```

What I have right now is just the basic stuff:

```
    filemame = "data.csv"
    file = open(filename, "r")
```

Not sure what I would do next.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Are you trying to convert it?

Comment: What you have right now is very nearly nothing! I suggest you look into the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: I would suggest reading the data with the [Python CSV library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: You should use IO write module that is file = open(filename, "w").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to convert the file, use the `QUOTE_ALL` constant from the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL), like this:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as input, open('out.csv','w') as output:
    reader = csv.reader(input)
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for line in reader:
        writer.writerow(line)
```